# How to Install SQLIte Plugin in Android + iOS in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, android-sqlite

I am building mobile app using phonegap and am using Phonegap 2.9.0 version and SQLite Plugin from the https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-Android.

I have include below js file in index.html,

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="SQLitePlugin.js"></script>`

then calling below method in deviceready event,

`var db =  window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("test.db", "1.0", "test", 20000);`

I have also copy the test.db Database to this folder "/data/data/"+pName+"/databases/".

I have followed exact steps given in above site but dont know something still missing and SQLite Plugin not working.

Please help me and if anyone have example then its better for me to understand.

Regards

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What is the issue? What exactly are you trying to do and what have you tried?

Answer (score -2):

Please change your code line to

```
var db = window.openDatabase("test.db", "1.0", "test", 20000);
```

instead of

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("test.db", "1.0", "test", 20000);
```

Comment: Thanks! But I want to connect my Phonegap app with SQLite DB and its not possible without using sqlitePlugin with their connection string.

Comment: Is any restrictions in size of the database.? I have loaded the resultSet JSONARRAY with more than 1MB of data, the application crashes, with the logcat information in the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310296/android-webview-loadurl-to-javascript-callback-function-sqlite-data . Please help me to resolve this.